I gave an unnecessary approval, how to withdraw it using polkadot.js?
Good afternoon! Faced with the problem that I'm being stealing monthly deployments of MANTA tokens on the manta Atlantic network, I think that somewhere I gave an unnecessary approval, how to withdraw it using polkadot.js? Is there a possibility like revoke.cash? Sid's phrase couldn't leak.
